# what determines the distance of the planets in the solar system originally?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

Kepler's third law states that The square of the orbital period of a planet is proportional to the cube of the semi-major axis of its orbit, or $\frac{R^3}{T^2}=constant$, which is the cornerstone of Newton's law of gravitation $\frac{GMm}{r^2}=mr\omega^2$, in which we also can obtain the relation $\frac{R^3}{T^2}=constant$. Clearly, a planet with bigger radius will rotate more slowly.

My **question** is

1. What determined the distance between the planets in the solar system originally?
2. Can there exist two palnets at the same orbit if they have the identical period?

Comment: Clearly a planet with a larger orbital radius will orbit slower than will a planet with a smaller orbital radius.

Comment: You're going to have to decide on "originally when?", as current models hold that there has been at least one period of significant evolution.

Comment: As to question two, two planets at Lagrange points to each other, L4/L5 could share an orbit.   Such a situation might be rare but it's possible.       But question one, the planets probably moved around a whole lot since formation.   We don't know precisely where they formed.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_migration

Comment: Thanks, I originally think the distance obeys some rules and can be exactly predicted. That is to say, we don't know why these planets stay at the locations they are located so far.